# Why is my BroadcastReceiver onReceive() running twice?

Tags: android

I have a custom BroadcastReceiver in my application to receive intents when the network connectivity is changed. For some reason, though, it's running twice whenever connectivity changes, and I don't know why.

**How can I fix this so that it only is triggered once on a network change?**

Note:
No, it's not in the manifest twice.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Here's the receiver code:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do stuff; This is running twice! 
    }
}
```

And here's the bit in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="NetworkStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Could you add some code please? (relevant code)

Comment: Dude add your code what u tried.

Comment: It is very hard to give you an answer without having some codepieces to find the problem. You could try to use the singleton pattern to avoid creating more than one object of the receiver, but I think that your problem is somewhere in your code and you should fix that rather than find a workaround

Comment: Sorry about that, guys, added some code. Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: Have a look deeper into chat CONNECTIITY_CHANGE does, it might send a broadcast for say, 1) disconnect from 3g network and 2) connect to wifi network, thus 2 onreceive calls

Comment: let me guess, are you checking 'internet connectivity'? So you are checking 'connectivity change' I doubt you might also be checking 'Wi-Fi' availability. I may be wrong, but checking it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving multiple broadcast is a device specific problem. Some phones just send one broadcast while other send 2 or 3. But there is a work around:

Assuming you get the disconnect message when the wifi is disconnected, I would guess the first one is the correct one and the other 2 are just echoes for some reason.

To know that the message has been called, you could have a static boolean that gets toggled between connect and disconnect and only call your sub-routines when you receive a connection and the boolean is true. Something like:
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static boolean firstConnect = true;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetInfo != null) {
        if(firstConnect) { 
            // do subroutines here
            firstConnect = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        firstConnect= true;
    }
}
```

}